# Chrome & Fan Speed

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, speedfan

I'm on Windows 7 on my Mac via Bootcamp... I notice that the fan goes from 3000 RPM to 5000-6000 RPM when Chrome is running and most of the time it's doing nothing. The CPU in the task manager for Chrome is 2-4%. What can I do?

PS: I think this problem became more obvious in past days... also in past days the outside temperature got higher (summer is finally here:)... could about 10 degrees more in outside temeprature influence this so much?

Comment: Did you recently cleaned your PC ? A vaccum cleaner and dry air spraycan are your best friends against noisy PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Chrome extensions that let you suspend activity after a defined period. This may reduce your fan's RPM:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en

Comment: trying all the other things first, but will try this extension as well, thanx!

Comment: so... this extension certainly helps... too bad I can't fix the problem without it.. but for now let it be.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe flash is hogging the CPU. It runs as a separate process.

I'll advise to install adblock to get rid of flash ads wich are consuming most of the ressources while browsing.

Comment: none of the tabs have flash running.. and I already have adblock. and the interesting (strange) thing to me is that CPU usage is a few percent... so don't know why the fan speed is up.. ut definitely when I close Chrome, fan speed gets down to 3k RPM

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure it is the CPU fan speed ? Maybe it's the GPU (or embedded GPU) that is changing mode when chrome is open. Some kind of optimus technology that switch GPU behavior.

Comment: Most probably CPU fan.. I can hear the typical fan noise... 

but as I wrote above (PS) it really may be that because of 10 degrees hotter outside temperature fans need to work harder... even 6000 RPM almost constantly... could be?

Comment: getting really tired of this :S spent the entire day trying to spot the pattern, but there is almost none.. except when I close Chrome, fan rpm goes down... sometimes it goes up after each tab opened and then after some time it goes down, sometimes it stays at 6000rpm.. tried in incognito mode without the extensions and it behaves similarly :/ Increased outside temperature causes higher rpm for sure, but the behaviour is still weird (like maximum rpm when there is no activity).. also tried IE9 and it didn't increase the fan speed.

Comment: UPDATE: IE also increases the fan speed after all... so it's some kind of a system issue... I posted another question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94508/6000-rpm-at-65c

Answer (score -1):

i have been trying to work out why my fan speed is up all the time when chrome is open. i even replaced the thermal paste on my cpu and gpu. do you have a second monitor plugged in? it could be the GPU working hard to use both screens.
worth a try. the great suspender makes no difference to fan speed. the cpu usage from chrome is 2-4% and the computer is running fine. its just the fan going nuts thats annoying.

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  This appears to be a comment.  In the future you should submit comments to the comment section only.